# Not getting array values when posting them in a form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have gone through various posts but can't find a solution to this problem:

I have a form with several rows of fields to insert in a database table with one Click of the submit button. This is the code of the HTML:

```
    <form action="filename.php?cartID=<?php echo $_GET['cartID'];?>&amp;customer_id=<?php echo $_GET['customer_id'];?>&amp;total_count=<?php echo $_GET['total_count'];?>&amp;action=add" method="post" id="add_participants" >
    <table>
     <?php for ($i=0, $n=$_GET['total_count']; $i<$n; $i++) { ?>

       <input type="hidden" name="customer_id[]" id="customer_id[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['customer_id'];?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="cartID[]" id="cartID[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['cartID'];?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="products_id[]" id="products_id[]" value="<?php echo $_GET['products_id'];?>" />
        <tr><td><label for="title[]">Title</label></td><td><select id="title[]" name="title[]">
         <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
       <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
       <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
        <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
       </select>
       </td>
       <td><label for="firstname[]">First Name</label></td><td><input type="text" id="firstname[]" name="firstname[]"/></td>

       <td><label for="surname[]">Surname</label></td><td><input type="text" id="surnam[]e" name="surname[]"/></td>
    <td><label for="email[]">E-mail</label></td><td><input type="text" id="email[]" name="email[]"/></td></tr>
   </table>

    <?php } ?>

<input value="Add participant" type="submit" />
```

On the action page the code is the following:

```
    for ($i=0, $n=$_GET['total_count']; $i<$n; $i++) {

            $title[$i] = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['title.$i]']);
            $firstname =tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['firstname.$i']);
            $surname =tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['surname.$i']);
            $email = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['email.$i']);
            $customer_id = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['customer_id.$i']);
            $cart_id = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['cartID.$i']);
            $products_id = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['products_id.$i']);

        $query = "INSERT INTO participants (title,Firstname,Surname,Email,customers_id,cart_id,products_id) VALUES ('$title[$i]', '$firstname[$i]', '$surname[$i]', '$email[$i]', $customers_id[$i], $cart_id[$i], $products[$i])";
            echo $query . "<br />";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

However, I cannot get the values of the $_POST variables into the variable arrays to use in the insert statement.

Can anyone help me with this please? I have tried different permutations of the code, and I'm still not getting anywhere.

Many thanks.

Comment: What does `tep_db_prepare_input` do? Usually things like that are a sign something is very, very wrong and [proper SQL escaping practices](http://bobby-tables.com/) are being disregarded.

Comment: Try one of the following: `$HTTP_POST_VARS["title[$i]"]` or `$HTTP_POST_VARS['title'][$i]`

Comment: `id="customer_id[]"` Really? :D

Comment: @chrislondon seriously?

Comment: Learn basic PHP syntax rules. `'` strings do **NOT** interpolate variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated.. you should be using `$_POST` instead.

Secondly, your processing doesn't really need to loop over a `for` loop. You could use `foreach` to loop over all posted values instead.

Example (untested):

```
foreach($_POST['customer_id'] as $key => $customerID) {
  $title     = !empty($_POST['title'][$key])     ? $_POST['title'][$key]     : "";
  $firstName = !empty($_POST['firstname'][$key]) ? $_POST['firstname'][$key] : "";
  // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your keeping the loop the same way, you need to make a change to how you refer to your array elements. change `$title[$i] = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['title.$i]']);` to

```
$title[$i] = tep_db_prepare_input($_POST['title'][$i]);
```

and change the rest of your assignments to follow the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `tep_db_prepare_input()` is of course a mistery, but apart from that it's true what Marc B. says: "Learn basic PHP syntax rules"

`$query = "INSERT INTO participants (title,Firstname,Surname,Email,customers_id,cart_id,products_id) VALUES ('$title[$i]', '$firstname[$i]', '$surname[$i]', '$email[$i]', $customers_id[$i], $cart_id[$i], $products[$i])";
echo $query . "
";`
This will output exactly what's between the double quotes. Try using:

`$query = "INSERT INTO participants (title,Firstname,Surname,Email,customers_id,cart_id,products_id) VALUES ('".$title[$i]."', '".$firstname[$i]."', '".$surname[$i]."', '".$email[$i]."', ".$customers_id[$i].", ".$cart_id[$i].", ".$products[$i].")";
echo $query . "
";`

Using `"{$array[$key]}"` within double quotes also works, but using `"$array[$key]"` within double quotes does not work.

Further, `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated. Use `$_POST`

Comment: `$_POST` has been around a billion years, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple errors that result in unintended values:

> $title[$i] = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['title.$i]'])

1. `foreach` is *definitely* clearer than a `for` loop
2. What others said: $HTTP_POST_VARS must be $_POST (or $_REQUEST)
3. Assuming that your mysterious tep_db_prepare_input() functions correctly, $HTTP_POST_VARS['title.$i]'] is syntactically incorrect. Single quotes mean variables are not parsed: your function is passed the (invalid) contents of $_POST[***'title.$i]'***]. I believe you meant to write $*POST["title*$i"] (where the "." is part of the field name. (Personally an underscore would be less confusing as "." has meaning in PHP.)

   1. So... fix all that and you should be good to go. Well, #2 & 3, at least.